# Can we prove this function is constant on $[0, b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to prove the following statement while working on another problem:

**Claim:** Let $f: [0,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = 0$. Assume that for any $\alpha \in  [0,b)$, there exists a neighborhood of $\alpha$, $U_\alpha$, such that $f$ is constant on $U_\alpha$. Then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,b)$.

Is this true? Or can we find a counterexample?

I tried defining an equivalence relation on $[0,b)$ by $x \sim y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$ iff $f$ is constant on $U_x \cup U_y$. However, I couldn't make it work.

Is there some formal/rigorous way to prove the claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Investigating an arbitrary neighborhood of $\inf\{x\in[0,b)|f(x)\neq 0\}$ will provide a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $c \in (0,b)$. Then $[0,c]$ is compact and $U_\alpha$ with $\alpha \in [0,c]$ form an open cover, hence there is a finite subcover. Now show that $f$ is constant on $[0,c]$. Since $c$ was arbitrary it follows that it is constant on $[0,b)$.